# How do I call a method from Azure Mobile Service custom Api?

Tags: android, azure-mobile-services

I have a following method form my AMS service and I want to call a method form my Android App.

```
 // POST: api/Bookings
    [ResponseType(typeof(Booking))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostBooking(Booking booking)
    {

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = booking.Id }, booking);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd be looking at something like this:

```
mClient.invokeApi("DefaultApi", new Booking(), Booking.class, new ApiOperationCallback<ToDoItem>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Booking result, Exception e, ServiceFilterResponse serviceFilterResponse) {

                }
            });
```

You'd want to replace "new Booking()" with the actual object you want to send up.